# Update document library column value for given row ID

Tags: document-library, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, updatelistitems, postman

I'm trying to update the `status` column in a document library where the name is "sharepoint_test.csv" and I'm following [this tutorial](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d046e2e2-41c7-4ce1-a7a0-9801fd88ad51/how-to-update-the-existing-item-details-in-document-library-using-rest-api-jquery-in-sp-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment) to do it.

URL:

**POST:URL**

```
https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/teams/global/commerce/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Data%20Sources')/items(4)
```

Body:

```
{"__metadata" {"type":"SP.Data.Data_x0020_SourcesItem"},"status":"even newer"}
```

I've also tried types `SP.FieldText` and `SP.Field`.

[image]

Here's my library:

```
Name                | Modified | Modified By | status
-----------------------------------------------------
sharepoint_test.csv | Apr 2    |  Dan        | new
```

Should become:

```
Name                | Modified | Modified By | status
-----------------------------------------------------
sharepoint_test.csv | Apr 2    |  Dan        | even newer
```

When I make the `POST` request in Postman, however, there is no error, the status comes back as `204 No Content`, but when I look back at the `status` column, it still remains as "new".

According to [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113155/rest-updating-list-field) and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7baa1477-9fe0-4338-8043-6ae101c9dbd4/updating-metadata-for-file-using-sharepoint-rest-api), I am doing it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The column names are case sensitive. Is the column "status" or "Status".

Are you sure the ID of the item is "4"?

Here's what I use that works (for AJAX), which except for the "Authorization" looks to be the same as your example:

```
/sites/testSite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Announcements')/Items(1)

{ "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
  "If-Match": "*",
  "X-RequestDigest": "__yourRequestDigest__" }

{ "__metadata": { "type": "SP.ListItem" }, "Title": "New title" }
```

I have a REST tester that I use to fine tune these requests: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2017/04/a-sharepoint-rest-api-tester-with-ajax.html

Comment: For `type`, it should be `[name of list]Item` right? I.e., `SP.Data.Data_x0020_SourcesItem` where `_x0020_` is representation of a space. The column name is `status`, but we've since changed it to `Import Status`, so I guess the final payload should be `{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.Data_x0020_SourcesItem"},"Import_x0020_Status":"TestUpdated"}`. You're setting the `Title` attribute, not the custom library field value?

Comment: Ah got it. Wrong ID as you mentioned. How can I get row by associated filename from a particular specific library rather than by ID?

Comment: Use a filter. For a list: _api/web/lists/getbytitle('Announcements')/items?$filter=Title eq 'Test announcement'  For a library file: _api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/Items?$filter=FileLeafRef eq 'AdventureWorksBikes.xlsx'&$select=Title,Id

Comment: For the REST API, use the static name of fields, so even if you changed the display name to "Import Status" it would still be just status for REST calls. To find the internal name, go to library settings, click the field to edit it, and look at the URL. It will end with &Field=<internal name>, and that's the name you should use for REST.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the status of Update Document metadata using REST API is :

> nocontent: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":204,"statusText":"No Content"}

So this word shouldn't worry you just check and see if the field changed?

Also you can use at least these two type of REST Endpoint for url for updation document metadata, which both of them return the above result as success!

```
url:response.d.ListItemAllFields.__metadata.uri,
url=_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+
"/_api/Web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/items("+itemId+")";
```